# Saving a string to a property list (plist) file?

Tags: iphone, arrays, plist

I've been trying to save to a property list file, however it's not working as its only saving the object to the array not the actual file itself, meaning that what it saves isn't obviously persisting.

```
[[category objectAtIndex:questionCounter] replaceObjectAtIndex:5 withObject:myString];
[category writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

I'm using this earlier on to save the property list files to the document directory so that I can edit and save to them:

```
NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameFull];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistFilePath]) {

    category = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];

    NSLog(@"Files exist.");

}
else {

    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileNamer ofType:@"plist"];
    category = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSLog(@"Files have been created.");

}
```

My property list is made up of arrays, within those arrays I'm trying to save my object (the string). I have a feeling it's something trivial but I can't spot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to save your array, you are passing in `filePath` which points to the main bundle directory, which you can't write to. You want to use `plistFilePath` instead, like so:

```
[category writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:YES];
```